# SharePoint 2010 Foundation Site Map

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sitemap

Is it possible to generate a site map listing of Shared Documents and Folders in SharePoint 2010 Foundation? I'm in the process of upgrading my company's SharePoint Intranet environment to 2010 Standard and would like to have a listing of the folder and file structure so that I can look into consolidating some folders when making the upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure understand you correctly, but I think you mean "Content and structure" in site settings. (_Layouts/sitemanager.aspx)